# how to restore system after change user folder name in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

my user folder name is C:\Users\明天, non english words "明天" brought me so much trouble when I program with python. So I login with administrator and change the "明天" into "tomorrow". after restart and login with original account, all desktop content  were gone. though I find they are still in C:\Users\明天, but environment has changed, all software installed non exist.
can I restore original system?

Comment: This link on the superuser.com will be able to help you with this.
https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10

Comment: I really hope I have seen it yesterday, but now, after I have changed name, their ways maybe too late

Comment: you can always make a new user account and delete the old one